# how can i make buttons with numbers from 0-9 that adds into a textbox when i press them

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to make a "numeric keyboard" that shows buttons with symbols from 0-9. When I press each button it is suppose to add up.
So lets say i press 3 , 4 then 1 it should say  341 on the text box or number box idk (srry im new).

I have only taken some examples from my teacher so i dont know if this is the right method.

I tried this on button 0:

```
    <button onclick="showZero()">0</button>
    <button onclick="">1</button>
    <button onclick="">2</button>
    <button onclick="">3</button>
    <button onclick="">4</button>
    <button onclick="">5</button>
    <button onclick="">6</button>
    <button onclick="">7</button>
    <button onclick="">8</button>
    <button onclick="">9</button>

    <br>

    <input type="text" id="txtZero">
```

```
window.onload = start;
 function start() {}

 function showZero()
 {
     var zero = document.getElementById("Number");

        zero.Value="0";

            document.querySelector("txtZero").appendChild(zero);
 }
```

Am i using wrong method? I saw my teacher example, but he was using this to generate more buttons and not numbers like im trying to do.

Comment: You should be using the same function for all buttons and passing a value to it. Also, you don't need to run anything on page load--just initialize a global variable containing your starting value. I suggest that you write out your intended behavior as pseudo-code so you're clear on the logic you seek.

Comment: This link will help you https://codeburst.io/making-a-calculator-with-basic-html-css-and-javascript-part-1-1e4288f0bea1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I edited my answer to provide a better answer that doesn't use inline event handling. I also wrapped the code into `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to make sure JS runs after the DOM is fully loaded.

```js
function ready() {
  
  // The textfield element
  textField = document.getElementById("field")
  // The reset button
  resetButton = document.getElementById("resetbtn")
  // Get all the buttons to an Array
  buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")
  
  // Add click event listener to all button elements and insert their inner text as value to the text field
  Array.prototype.forEach.call (buttons, (button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      textField.value += button.innerText
    })
  })

  // Add click event listener to reset button
  resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    textField.value = null
  })
  
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```css
input, button {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">0</button>
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
<button class="btn">6</button>
<button class="btn">7</button>
<button class="btn">8</button>
<button class="btn">9</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="field"><button id="resetbtn">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Don't encourage inline event handling. They are dangerous and don't work when there's a Content-Security-Policy

Comment: what does the inline event handling ?  does it mean to put javascript in html file? srry im new

Comment: @Achu I just provided a quick answer to what you were trying to do. Inline event handling is the `onclick` attribute that ControlAltDel has mentioned. You can actually give classnames or ids to each button and then add Click event handlers in your javascript file.

Comment: @Ozgur Sar also the += it means it will add? this is what i had in mind yes

Comment: Yes, it justs adds the new string to the existing value of the text field

Comment: @Achu I edited my answer to remove the inline event handling that ControlAltDel has mentioned above.

Comment: @OzgurSar Ok Ill look at this

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code to it:

- Add function setNumber to set number in field text.
- Change function showZero to resetNumber if contains the value in field text insert zero.

```js
function resetNumber()
      {
          document.getElementById("field").value = '0';
      }
      
      function setNumber(number) {
        document.getElementById("field").value = document.getElementById("field").value === '0' ?  '' : document.getElementById("field").value += number;
      }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="resetNumber()">Reset</button>
   <button onclick="setNumber(0)">0</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(1)">1</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(2)">2</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(3)">3</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(4)">4</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(5)">5</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(6)">6</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(7)">7</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(8)">8</button>
    <button onclick="setNumber(9)">9</button>
    <br />
        <input type="text" id="field" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit with events inline.

Comment: Add also function resetNumber.

Comment: yes but remove the "onclick"s and use addEventListener instead